# Page refresh required on redirect to html file in IIS on I.E

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, iis, webforms

So I have a web forms app in which I have a page with the sole purpose of redirecting to an html file and displaying it. Now this works perfect in Visual Studio, but when I run it from IIS it works well the first time I load the page, but when I change the html file then open it again it still has the old content, but will update if I click refresh. I figured I'd just refresh the page manually in `Page_Load()` with

```
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Refresh", "<script>window.location.reload();</script>");
```

but that got me nowhere. I've tested it a few times and this is only a problem in I.E., chrome and firefox work as expected. Do I just have to live with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Either set the page to not be cached (iis caching settings) or append a random number as a query string to the html page to force it to be downloaded each request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm) is what solved it for me. I ended up just throwing

```
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
</HEAD>
```

at the bottom of the html file and that made it happy. This was in a comment but I was restricted from answering so I reposted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a cache problem, as stated by nakchak.

I think you will find the solution on this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11225/Disabling-browser-s-back-functionality-on-sign-out):

In resume at `Page_Load` use the following code to prevent cache:

```
Response.Buffer=true;
Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires =-1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
//Bellow this is not needed, just for reference from original post 
if(Session["SessionId"] == null)
    {
     Response.Redirect ("WdetLogin.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense and seems like the right answer, but I tried it before and after the Redirect, with and without a refresh, and turned off Output caching on IIS (although looking at their documentation it doesn't actually cache html pages). Unless you have an idea of what I did wrong I might just change the file name every time per nakchak's suggestion. Although I don't like that idea as much.

Comment: [Here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm) is what solved it for me. I ended up just throwing `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">` and `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">`
into the html file in an ending `<HEAD>` block and that made it happy. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Glad you found a solution